# Sencha Touch Store config properties only in "__proto__"?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, prototype, store

I transfered my code from ST 2.0 to a 2.3.1 install. So I have some properties in my store's config object. But when I try to use the properties e.g. `store.config.onlineURL` the browser throws an undefined error. So when I inspect the object in the chrome dev tools I can find my custom properties in `store.config.__proto__`. But why is this happening? Have something changed in defining objects?

```
Ext.define("MY.SimpleStore", {
   extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
   requires: ['MY.model.SimpleModel'],

   config: {
       model: 'MY.model.SimpleModel',
       storeId: 'simplestore',
       proxy: {
              type: 'localstorage',
              id: 'simplestore'
       },
       jsonUrl: 'jsonfiles/simplestore.json',
       onlineURL: 'http://example.com/simplestore.php'
   },


});
```

So how can I access `store.config.jsonUrl and onlineURL` ?

Answer (score 0):

Forgot about the generated getters/setters.

`store.getJsonUrl()`